# What are the best practices for preventing SQL creep?

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, design-patterns, language-agnostic, refactoring

I have a webapp written in PHP using a MySQL database backend. This question could just as easily apply to any language and application trying to use an SQL database and MVC OOP design.

**How do you keep your SQL code restricted to the Model?**

There's a rather longer story specific to my case behind the question.  As previously mentioned I'm working on a PHP/MySQL/AJAX website.  I designed it using OOP and MVC design principles - with a Model, View and Controller.  I managed to keep the view elements - such as markup and styling - restricted completely to the View and to make them reusable fairly easily.  I thought I had done the same with SQL code.  But as work has progressed, it's become pretty clear that the Model needs some serious refactoring.

The way I'd found to keep the SQL in the Model was to encapsulate every single SQL query in its own Query object.  And then when I needed to call some SQL in the View or Controller I would access the query through a factory.  No SQL code exists in the Controller or the View.

But this has become extraordinarily tedious.  I don't think I'm actually gaining anything by doing this and am spending far too much time creating queries with names like "SelectIdsFromTableWhereUser".  The factory for the queries is approaching thousands of lines.  A bit of searching in Eclipse has revealed that the vast majority of these queries are used in one or two places and never again.  Not good.

I know that in good MVC you want to keep the SQL completely separate from the Controller or the View.  But at this point, it seems to me like it would have been better to just place the SQL where it was needed in the code and not bother trying to bury it and database code deep in the Model.  These queries are only being used once, why bother encapsulating them?

Is it that important to keep the SQL separate from Controller or the View?  What is gained by doing this?  What is lost by allowing it to spread?  How do you solve this problem?

**Edit** Per request, here's a little more detail on my model.

There are two portions to it.  The Tables portion and the Queries portion.  The Tables portion holds the domain objects - mostly designed as wrappers around class objects that are exact analogues of the tables in the database.  For example, there might be a database table `Foo` that has fields `id`, `name`, and `type`.  There will be a Table object (`class FooTable`) that has an array with fields 'id', 'name' and 'type'.  It would look like this:

```
class FooTable extends MySQLTable {
    private $id;
    private $data;
    private $statements;

    public function __construct($id, $data=NULL, $populate=false) {
         // Initialize the table with prepared statements to populate, update and insert.  Also,
         // initialize it with any data passed in from the $data object.
    }

    public function get($field) {}
    public function set($field, $value) {}
    public function populate() {}
    public function update() {}
    public function insert() {}
}
```

If there's a `fooBar` database table that has a one to many relation (one `Foo` many `Bars`) with fields `id`, `fooID`, and `bar` then there will be a `FooBar` Table object (`class FooBarTable`) which will look pretty much exactly the same as the above `FooTable`.

The `FooTable` and many `FooBarTable` objects will both be contained in the `Foo` object.  Give the `Foo` object factory an id to a `Foo` table and it populates itself with `Foo`'s data and all of its `Bar`s and their data.

The Query objects are used for pulling out those `Foo` ids in the order they are needed.  So, if I want the `Foo` objects ordered by date, vote or name, I need a different query object to do it.  Or if I want to select all `Foo` objects that have a `Bar` in a certain range.  I need a query object.

Most of the time I use the Table objects (the wrappers, not the base tables) to interact with the database.  But when it comes to selecting which table objects, that's where the queries come in.

During original design I didn't think there would be too many queries and I thought they were going to be things that would see reuse.  Since there might be several places where I'd want the `Foo`s in date order.  But it hasn't worked out that way.  There are way more of them than anticipated and most of them are one offs, used once in some View or Command and then never again.  I also thought the queries might encapsulate fairly complex SQL and it would be good to have them as objects so that I would always be sure to give them the data they needed and it would be a relatively sanitized environment in which to test the SQL query itself.  But again, it didn't work out that way.  Most of them contain pretty simple SQL.

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question. You followed what seemed to be a sensible "best practice," only to find that this practice has become burdensome for marginal benefit. It's good to be "correct," but it's better to be "effective."

Comment: @Robert Understood, but I was wondering if maybe just the way I was following the "best practice" was what was causing me problems.  Are there other ways to keep SQL restricted to the model other than encapsulating queries that would be better for lots of single use queries?

Comment: @Robert I think it's a bit premature to toss abstraction to the wind just because Daniel isn't making good abstractions.

Comment: @timedev: Oh, I'm all for good abstractions, if that's what the problem is.

Comment: @Robert - see my answer (which was somewhat aborted, I'll admit).  It sounds like Daniel is just writing boilerplate models to "keep SQL out of his controllers", without producing any useful abstractions.

Comment: "A bit of searching in Eclipse has revealed that the vast majority of these queries are used in one or two places and never again. Not good."  Funny, I don't recall reuse being a requirement of MVC.  Why would you expect an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement to be used in more than one place, other than to expose the ability in multiple places?

Comment: @timdev: I agree with your assessment.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: If any function (not just a query) is only called from one place, that's a suggestion that your abstraction isn't very good. It might be good enough. But if every new view requires new functions to be added to the model, as is likely to be the case when the functions on the model are typically used from only one view, then you aren't gaining as much from your "encapsulation" of the model as you might.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: User interaction has nothing to do with encapsulation.  Rather, you've made the situation more difficult to debug, because it could be coming from x, y, z or a.  That's besides letting the user learn the system (IE: "you can do it here... here, there... OH! and there too...").  The fundamental issue here is you don't understand what a SQL query is, and what it needs to perform best.  You don't write dynamic SQL solely for the sake of reuse.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Well, the *questioner's* fundamental issue is that he's churning out dozens of single-use factory functions, each containing a different SQL snippet, resulting a model with too large a surface. Your fundamental issue might be something else. MVC doesn't forbid crummy interfaces, but it doesn't encourage them either. If it was necessary for the sake of performance, then a crummy interface might be justified, but I don't think there's any such indication here.

Comment: @Daniel: sounds like you might benefit from an ORM. I don't know what's a good one for PHP, but using an ORM keeps the SQL in the model (or ideally in the ORM), by surrounding the data layer in a more friendly interface that's queryable without writing SQL. Details depend on the language and the ORM, but for instance you don't need `SelectIdsFromTableWhereUser("Bob")` if you can write something like `table.query().filter(user="Bob").select("id")`, or what-have-you. The ORM generates the SQL from that, and that code appears in the model or the view according to why you're writing it.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: MVC or other framework, the whining isn't going to stop about not comprehending the reality to using a SET based environment for persistence.  The OP can move to ORM, and then eventually come back to ask "why doesn't it perform well?!"

Comment: @OMG Ponies: or most likely not come back, because the ORM performs fine for the questioner's requirements. It's possible that this questioner is one of the small minority who need astonishingly high performance from their relational database, but not all that probable.

Comment: @Daniel: actually, just noticed in your comment below that you're using the ids to instantiate your objects anyway (and presumably pull all the columns at that point). So the ORM code would more likely be even better: more along the lines of `table.query().filter(user="Bob")`. Or if "user" is a foreign key, maybe `bob = user.get(name="Bob"); bob.foos()`. The point of the ORM is to give you useful *general* tools for manipulating the data, which is what SQL does, but designed with an eye to your OO usage.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Data grows, and systems need to scale.  What good is academically sound programming, whose performance degrades the more often people use it?  I'll never get why people will run to learn & use various tech, except if it's SQL.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I'm not talking about "academic soundness", I'm talking about writing programs having components with clear and consistent interfaces. I could flip what you say around, and wonder why performance junkies and premature optimizers are demanding that I should keep my machine 90% idle instead of only 80% idle. It seems sensible to me to be aware of the options and choose the best for a given situation. The questioner is obviously already aware of SQL, so I offer something else.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Data grows--that's not premature optimization, that's *reality*.  What good are a clear & consistent interfaces if they require using tech that won't serve the end user consistently over time?  None, because what you advocate is purely *academic*; the business & end user don't care that you used the Decorator/etc design pattern--they care that the system doesn't take so long to return results that they need to leave it running for 5+ minutes.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: So just to be clear, are you asserting that every single web app in the world that uses an ORM runs unacceptably slowly, or merely that the questioner's webapp will run too slow if he uses one? Design is important to the extent that it affects how quickly new features can be added to the app, and bugs prevented and fixed. Last I checked users care about that too. If it gets to 5 minutes, sure, performance needs fixing, but most users aren't sitting with a stopwatch trying to work out whether a page took 50ms or 100ms to generate.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: You're trying to put words in my mouth, while not addressing the points I make--I'll take that as admittance your counter argument has no merit.  I admit, I expected better from a high rep account.  I stated that data growth depends on use, which means time... Maintenance takes time--ORM or SQL, still need to find the issue, reproduce, test, and regression test.  The time to fix depends on familiarity with the codebase and business, and the effort necessary to fix the issue.  That's not even touching on database design, or ability of ORM to accommodate needs.

Comment: @OMG: I'm trying to make any kind of sense of what you're saying. Obviously it's true that data grows. I don't see how that's relevant to the issue of whether the questioner's app would benefit from a different design, that simplifies his code, perhaps at some performance cost, which perhaps is measurable. I'm somewhat sympathetic if your SQL-tuning abilities aren't as highly valued as you'd like, but not to the extent that I'll expect that everybody do things your way just because you have higher rep than me.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: What you advocate is refactoring code that is more prone to perform negatively.  Does that sound like a good practice to you?

Comment: @OMG: more prone to perform negatively than what? Based on the questioner's description of what the code does, "The queries are used to obtain lists of ids from the database that are then used to instantiate individual domain objects", I don't think I accept the premise that switching to an ORM is especially likely to degrade performance. It might improve it, make it worse, or leave it about the same. If a particular change cuts down the code base without an unacceptable performance cost then I think it's good practice to make that change, and certainly worth being aware of the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with the last question : what is gained is separation of concerns or in plain english "Keeping things together which belong together".  A key word here is belong, which is a rather subjective word.

In the early PHP days a lot of people found that whatever is on a single page "belongs" together. Since PHP used to be an acronym for "Personal Home Page" its design goal was small sites with a couple of pages and then this sense of belonging makes absolute sense.

When things grow, the sense of belonging shifts. When we get a complex data model which needs to be kept consistent and which must evolve over time, then suddenly the operations on this "model" start to "belong" together because it becomes too difficult to dig out the operations and SQL queries all over the place. So in order to keep control we need all model operations on the same page.

As a practical approach I like to draw a line in the sand between the UI and the Model and define a API there which encapsulates the mini user goals (User wants to see the promotions --> getPromotions methods is needed, User wants to add something to the cart : addToCart method is needed, etc...).

I like to draw the line here, because it captures the User's desires, the UI's responsibility is to make the user get there in an easy and effective way, the service/model/repository layer responsibility is to realise that desire.

If done properly, it is also on a level 1 step removed from the User. Many developers however confuse what the User wants with the features that need to be implemented. Then you get very ineffective service methods like saveProject (A User does not want the project to be saved, she just wants it to be there next time she logs in. It is taken for granted, and as such it has no place in the service API). This implementation based API leads to layers of almost empty wrapper methods.

Things like repositories etc, are a way to structure this service layer.

This user-goal oriented API approach also has the tendency to clean up the views (the content of the display elements can be fetched with a handful service calls) and the controllers (an action then consists of the normal sanitizing and typically a single method call).

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)? Seems to me like this would be a nice, simple way to encapsulate the SQL.  Your current approach seems unnecessarily complicated.

The NerdDinner Tutorial [has a good example](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm) of repository usage in an MVC context; even though it is not in PHP, hopefully it will give you an idea of how this pattern works.

Comment: +1 for suggesting something concrete.  It sounds like OP needs to dig into design patterns in general, and figure out what approach is likely to work for his problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to give good advice without knowing what kinds of things you're doing, but it's clear that something is probably very wrong.

From what you're said, it sounds like you're right in thinking that your model needs some major refactoring.  In fact, it sounds like it needs some serious redesign (meaning the API your controllers and views use to access it will change).

Some thoughts:

You say:

> The way I'd found to keep the SQL in
>   the Model was to encapsulate every
>   single SQL query in its own Query
>   object. And then when I needed to call
>   some SQL in the View or Controller I
>   would access the query through a
>   factory. No SQL code exists in the
>   Controller or the View.Controller or the View.

This makes me think you're missing the point.  You model should be more than a bunch of boilerplate code so that SQL doesn't (gasp!) show up in some controller.  Your model ought to be a **model of your domain object** -- what you've described is just an inefficient proxy to SQL.

It might be helpful if you posted some examples of how your model gets used.  That is to say, edit your question to include some examples of how your controllers and views use your models.

Comment: There are two parts to my model.  There is a section that models the domain objects.  The queries are used to obtain lists of ids from the database that are then use to instantiate individual domain objects.

Comment: Okay, edited the original question with more details about the model.